# Storing static final constants in Spring?

Tags: spring, static, constants

I have a file with a bunch of static final String variables:

```
static final String ENTER = "Enter"; 
static final String EXIT = "Exit"; 
static final String FORCE = "Force";
```

And so on. Probably around 20 of these.

However I want to define and load these values off my Spring XML rather than define them in the .java file. How would I add these declarations in my spring xml file and how would my .java file look afterwards?

Would I do something like:

```
<bean id="enter" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="ENTER">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="Enter"/> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

or

Will the use of Util:Constant be handy here, and how?

Also in either case, what will my Java file now look like? I want to avoid having a bunch of Setters/Getters for all my 20-30 final variables.

Note: I am using Spring 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Most suitable method probably to use Spring properties. Create a file **myconstant.properties**, place it on classpath root and set your constants there

```
com.mycompany.myapp.ENTER=Enter 
com.mycompany.myapp.EXIT=Exit
com.mycompany.myapp.FORCE=Force
```

And create a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer on your application context xml. The property then can be substituted using `${..}` syntax

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/myconstant.properties"/>

<bean class="com.mycompany.SomeClass">
  <property name="blah" value="${com.mycompany.myapp.ENTER}"/>
</bean>
```

This can also be injected into bean class

```
@Component
public MyClass {
  @Value("${com.mycompany.myapp.ENTER}") private String ENTER;
  ..
}
```

Comment: what edits would need to go into the .java file? Do you have to add any annotations?

Comment: Edited my answer. Try the `@Value` annotation

Comment: One more question/concern, do I have to add setters/getters. I've noticed often with Spring beans, you have to have setters/getters for each field of your class. It would be a big mess if I had to provide 20 setters/getters for each istance variable of my class

Comment: Yes getters and setters are recommended approach, otherwise if you refactor your code you could end up with much bigger mess. Use eclipse to automatically generate getters and setters